# SQL Auto Number Error

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment

I built a vb.net winform in visual studio. the user can import records into a SQL table that is in an Access DB.

The first column is an auto record count. I have noticed a few missing records. The weird thing is the record count is there. for example, I will see 80, 81, 83 and so on, but 82 is missing.

The weird thing is in that same button click I insert their click count into another table and that goes through, therefore I am able to see they clicked the import button and at what time, but no record was inserted for them.

I just think this is weird since the table is indicating no record for the ID number of where the record would be. I have a try catch around the insert but it doesn't seem to be catching when the insert function fails.

Answer (score 0):

> I will see 80, 81, 83 and so on, but 82 is missing

This can be the result of an aborted insert (for example - the insert was trying to insert a `null` to a non-nullable column).

When that happens, the database will skip the value that would have been used if the insert had succeeded.

**This is normal database operation** and is not a thing to worry about.